# Creating objects for each element

Tags: java, object

I'd like to do something like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/shittyprogramming/comments/48lbyf/reinstalled_eclipse_on_the_computer_i_used_in/d0kt93t):

> create a class with the following properties: `String name; int atomicNumber; String symbol; double mass;`
>
> create an initializer so you can just do `new Element("Hydrogen", 1, "H", 1.0079)` and a `toString` method.
>
> now create an object for each element. note that now, you only have one line of code per element. you can store these in an array (or a dictionary that uses the name as the key).
>
> when the user inputs the name, you can just look for it in the array (or just get the value from the key in the dictionary) and call `toString` on the object.
>
> why this way? imagine that now you have to add a line in your output with the number of valence electrons for each atom. this would require a line or two in toString, rather than one line for each element.

How would I go about doing this? What would the class with the properties look like?

I tried making one:

```
public class Structure {
    String name;
    int age;
    String color;

    public void add(String name, int age, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

But I'm not quite sure how to go on, and `Structure.add("Adele",25,"Grey");` works but doing it with another overwrites the data.

Comment: why do you have the fields name, age and color in your code when the requirements ask for String name; int atomicNumber; String symbol; double mass;

Comment: You should choose an answer so others know what solution worked for you, and so you can give credit to those who offered their help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make a new object for each element. So the class's "add" method, shouldn't be called "add". Since it won't be adding anything. Instead, let's make that a constructor. Like this:

```
public Structure(String name, int age, String color) {
    //The inside stays the same
}
```

Now we can make objects like this:

```
Structure s = new Structure("matthew", 22, "BLUE");
```

We can store those objects in an array like this:

```
Structure[] structures = new Structures[numStructures];
for(int i = 0; i < numStructures; i++) {
    structures[i] = new Structure("whatever", 99, "some color")l
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to store multiple `Structure` objects in a list.

```
public class Structure {
    String name;
    int age;
    String color;

    public Structure(String name, int age, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Then, in the place you are creating objects.

```
List<Structure> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Structure("john",25,"blue"));
list.add(new Structure("sally",15,"green"));
list.add(new Structure("mark",35,"red"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of a class is that you can create new objects of that classtype. In Java you create *instances* of a class like so:

```
Structure instance1 = new Structure();
```

In your case, you have an `add` method, so you could call that on your new object to set its properties:

```
instance1.add("Adele", 25, "Grey");
```

but it would make more sense to define a *constructor*:

```
public Structure(String name, int age, String color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.color = color;
}
```

I would suggest reading up on some basic [object-oriented programming concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Answer (score 0):

Your "first try" should be

```
public class Structure {
  String name;
  int age;
  String color;

  public Structure(String name, int age, String color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

Instead of writing a method add, you create a constructor: no return type (remove the `void`), and must use the same name as the class name.

For your question, use the properties `name, atomicNumber, symbol and mass` instead of the properties `name, age and color` as in your example.  You must also use the class name `Element` instead of  `Structure`.